# What does "note of office" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, expressions

I am trying to translate the following text, which was composed around 1910:

> Let him read through this note of his office, and sign it, paying the sum of Three Guineas for the volume containing...

This document defines the task for a grade in a study curriculum, so I believe "office" means "grade" in the sense of a "post", an "appointment", a "position".

I have found a single other ocurrence of the expression "note of office" with a similar context:

> “I took a note of office when I went into the Army to uphold the Constitution. That all stays with me till the day I die, so I had no choice,” he said.

https://www.theepochtimes.com/after-supreme-court-win-camp-constitution-raises-christian-flag-at-boston-city-hall-plaza_4643726.html

What does "note of office" mean in this context? Is "note" here an uncommon synonym for "oath"?

Comment: It's not a term I recognise but I suspect that it is an old term for what we would now call "a statement of terms and conditions of employment". However it would be interesting to see what the three guineas was for, charging someone a fairly considerable amount of money at the start of their employment is strange to modern sensibilities and might even be illegal these days.

Comment: @BoldBen sorry for not providing a lot of source; the three guineas are payment for a "volume" of papers that the student must read.

Comment: Thanks Pedro, I hadn't realised that the 'office' was the entry into the examination. That makes it even more obscure. I still tend to think that "the note of _his_ office" in the case of the student and "a note of office" in the case of the ex-soldier in the other quote are formal statements of the legal position of the person entering an occupational situation and that signing the document indicates legal acceptance of the terms; as I said similar to a new employee signing a statement of the terms and conditions of employment. However I have neither knowledge nor proof of this.

Comment: “took a note of office” is new to me; I assume “a note” is a mishearing (perhaps by a speech-to-text device?) of “an oath”.

Comment: I am coming back to this question after some time, and perhaps I failed to fully explain the original context. The paper I was translating contains instructions for a recently admitted member of a study fraternity. The study program is organized in "grades", so in this context people are said to "assume grades" and "be admitted to grades". The member does profess an oath at the time of admission. That is why I suspected that this language may have meant "taking an oath".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Office" here does mean "post". It does not mean "grade". A "note of his office" will be some official memo/form that is part of his office. For example a "note of his office" for a housing officer might be a form declaring that such and such a house is now vacant, not in habitable condition, or now tenanted etc.

A "note of office" does not mean oath.